# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable using itertuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through the rows of a CSV file where I saved a list of my followers, with the data associated to the subscribing event and a flag that specifies if I already unsubscribed from the specific follower.

Here is an example of the file:

[List of follower with data of subscription and unsubscribe flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/142Bl.png)

Right now I am trying to build a loop in that way:

I try to calculate a new variable `time_d` that gives me the number of days since the subscription.
Then I will do an `if` statement in which I ask:

1. if the subscription occurred more than 7 days ago AND my `flag_unsubscribe = 'NO'` then try etc.

```
df = pd.read_csv("follower.csv",parse_dates=[1])
for row in df.itertuples():
    time_d = pd.Timestamp("today") - row[2]
    print(time_d)
    converted_time_d = pd.DataFrame([time_d]).apply(np.float32)
    print(converted_time_d," - ",row[3])
    #if all((all(converted_time_d)>=7) and all(str(row[3]))!='1.0'):
    if all((all(converted_time_d)<=7) and str(row[3])=="NO"):
        try:
```

Right now, I am receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive\Desktop\XXX\unfollow_by_profile.py", line 26, in <module>
    if all((all(converted_time_d)<=7) and str(row[3])=="NO"):
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Can someone help me?
I tried to look on a similar post, but I did not find anything that could fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`all()` accepting `Iterable` and returns `bool`.
The problem that you trying to pass to `all()` non-iterable type.
If you want to check multiple conditions in `all()` put conditions to list or tuple and pass it to function:

```
if all([condition1, condition2]): ...
```

Maybe you need:

```
if all([converted_time_d <= 7, row[3] == "NO"]): ...
```

But in your case with only two conditions maybe it will be enough to use simple `and`?

```
if converted_time_d <= 7 and row[3] == "NO": ...
```

and I think you don't need to use `str(row[3])` but just `row[3]` because there is nothing you can convert to string type from non-string type to get "NO" value :) only if you have bytes type.